# Using jQuery to show div depending on return value from servlet

Tags: java, jquery, jstl

I want to use the language parameter returned through servlet to decide which div to view, I am using jsp/servlet technieque,

I receive lang param from request

```
<c:set var="lang" value="${lang}" scope="request"></c:set>
```

how can I use jquery to solve this thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would assign your JSTL parameter to a JavaScript variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var lang = "${lang}";  // When JSP gets processed, this becomes var lang = "EN", etc.

$("#"+lang).show();    // Assumes you have a div id="EN" or whatever.
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can decide this on the server since you have the information that you need there. FOr instance:

```
 <c:choose>
    <c:when test='${lang=="EN"}'>
       <div>English</div>
    </c:when>
    <c:when test='${lang=="ES"}'>
       <div>Espaniol</div>
    </c:when>
 </c:choose>
```

I am not sure where jQuery comes in since that is on the client.